# What is involved in replacing a missing speed selector on my two speed hammer drill?

Tags: repair, tools, drill, powertools

I have a Bosch CSB 500-2 2 speed hammer drill for wood, concrete, and steel. As can be seen in the image below, the speed selection knob is missing.

[image: Side view of drill highlighting missing speed selector]

Would it be simply buying a new selector, which I imagine is pretty simple and inexpensive, and just opening the machine and slotting it in, or is this repair more complex than I envision? If more complex, I would appreciate a short summary of what needs to be done, but I am not looking for instructions on how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

> **I imagine is pretty simple and inexpensive**

Spare parts for older machines are often either [unavailable](http://www.powertoolspares.com/tool/bosch/spares-and-accessories-for-percussion-drill-csb-500-2/0603147550/spares/) or surprisingly [expensive](http://www.mtmc.co.uk/Bosch-CSB-500-2-/-0603167042-Spare-Parts__p-88015.aspx) (e.g. armature £37).

> **is this repair more complex than I envision?**

You'd need to open up the case and see if there is any other internal damage.

You might need to fabricate or improvise a speed selector. For example you might use polymorph or adapt a metal part.

A new Bosch drill of that sort can be purchased for [£35-£50](http://www.diy.com/departments/bosch-680w-240v-corded-keyless-chuck-hammer-drill-psb680re/195931_BQ.prd?LSB_D_B3) (PSB500RE PSB680RE are often available on special offer at 30% lower price). A cheap store-brand drill might be [£20 or less](http://www.diy.com/departments/500w-corded-impact-drill-vid500hf/735538_BQ.prd).

Links and prices are illustrative examples, a web-search will find local equiavalents.

Comment: Thanks, @RedGrittyBrick. What you mean by `use polymorph`? A new drill would be nice, but my beauty of a press drill does 99% of what I want. I'm actually asking because I'm trying to sell this drill, and trying to guestimate by how much it is devalued. And maybe offer the buyer some advice.

Comment: Oh yes, the contemporary drills look almost exactly like my older one, so I guess there's a very good chance they even still use the same selector. Well, when I say contempory I actually mean one I owned about 6 years ago, where this one is well, well over ten years old, but you could hardly tell them apart.

Comment: @ProfK. [Polymorph](http://www.maplin.co.uk/p/mindsets-polymorph-250g-n14at) is a low temperature thermoplastic that you can heat to >60C using a cup of hot water and hand-mould it to a desired shape. When cool it is as hard as nylon. I'm assuming that the switch mechanism of your drill doesn't get that hot (which is certainly questionable). I suspect the drill is worth less than $15, possibly much less.

Comment: With the selector, I could probably sell the drill for about ZAR300, or +- £18. Some things are more expensive in South Africa. A new, smaller, single-speed sells for between ZAR500 and ZAR1000.

Comment: The armature is the *engine*, the beating heart of the machine, so why is 37 quid surprising?  That seems like a very good price.   If you paid 9 for lawnmower blades, you wouldn't be surprised if  the engine is 500.